# How to build apk from expo react native app in latest version?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, apk

I want to build apk of my expo react native app but without using expo.dev
Since they have a limit of 30 builds, and its very slow as well.
Is there any way to build the apk locally?
I ran the expo run:android command, it generated android folder, I tried to use android studio to build apk, but I got the development build instead.

I also tried editing eas.json, it gives the apk on their website itself, but is there any way to generate apk locally? Also it works in my one project, but in another project of mine, it doesn't work, I still get playstore build only.

Or how to effectively use the update command instead of making new apk everytime, because free account gets 10000 updates in a month, so that is suffice for me. But not able to figure out the update part.